# Coldfusion passing variable through url

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am trying to pass the ID of a username through the URL (this part works). Then on to the next page where I display the user's information. However I cannot get the latter part to work correctly.  Below is my code

Working URL code:

```
<a href="memberdetails.cfm?id='#custlist.customerID#'">#custlist.userName#<br />
```

The non working part:

```
<cfquery name="custlist" datasource="homesource">
       id = $_GET['customerID'] ;
   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = id
</cfquery>
```

Any help with this problem would be welcomed. I am just starting to learn ColdFusion (like today). This application is just for me playing about, testing the waters. So if possible, no debates on me passing the id through the url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reference a URL variable, simply refer to it prefixed by `url`. You are passing customerID to the `id` parameter, so you'll specify `url.id`. Within a string, you'll need to surround it with pound signs: `"#url.id#"`

Here is how you would change your query to use the URL variable from your sample:

```
<cfquery name="custlist" datasource="homesource">
    SELECT * 
    FROM customers 
    WHERE customerID = <cfqueryparam value="#url.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
</cfquery>
```

For extra safety, be sure to use `cfqueryparam` to bind variables to your SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i get the following error
Invalid data '1' for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER.
the '1' changes to what ever the ID is on a given user do you know how i can get around that i did a quick google and it says it has to be an int? but it is an int :/

Comment: The number 1 is definitely an int. Is there a space or other whitespace character in front or behind it?

Comment: theres '' in the url memberdetails.cfm?id='2' but i dont have any '' in the code my url is now this

<a href="memberdetails.cfm?id=#custlist.customerID#">#custlist.userName#<br />

so i dont know i'll spend the rest of the night on this and figure out it was something simple lol

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have told you how to solve the problem at hand.  This is something extra.  You had this:

```
<cfquery name="custlist" datasource="homesource">
id = $_GET['customerID'] ;
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = id
</cfquery>
```

The mistake was to use php code in a ColdFusion application.  It would be silly of course, but you could have done this:

```
<cfquery name="custlist" datasource="homesource">
<cfset id = url.customerID>
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = id
</cfquery>
```

The point is that you can put other coldfusion tags inside a cfquery block.  Here is a more practical example of that.

```
<cfquery name="custlist" datasource="homesource">
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
<cfif StructKeyExists(url,"customerid")>
WHERE customerID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.customer_id#">
</cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thank you, as you can see from my example i was really trying to edit my php code that was working as that was all i could think of after several other methods failed. this answer has helped me quite a bit and i even learnt something from it! so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfquery name="custlist" datasource="homesource">
   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"   value="#url.customer_id#">
</cfquery>
```

Never use the client data, in this case the URL, directly in a query. The integer param will prevent all SQL injection hack attempts. It also improves performance because of the way the database communication takes place (sql prepared statements).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest purchasing a book on coldfusion for this is the most basic thing they will teach you.

```
<cfquery name="custlist" datasource="homesource">
   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = <Cfqueryparam  cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.id#">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: from experience most books are rubbish that don't explain how or why things work and just give you a block of code to copy, but i am on Amazon looking for books to buy if you have and good books you'd like to recommend please do  :)

Comment: There are also online tutorials.  easycfm.com comes to mind.  As far as books go, the CF Web Application Construction Kit by Ben Forta is pretty darned good.

Comment: yeh i prefer online tutorials and what not to books. i will check out that easycfm one thanks.

Comment: cfquery is not the most basic thing. <cfset> probably is.